# Why do I get a nil after changing the order of two lines?

Tags: ruby

In the `titleize` method, why do I get nil when I reverse the order of the lines containing `words.first.capitalize` and `words.join(" ")`?

```
def titleize(x)
words = x.split(" ").collect do |word|
    if %w(the and over).include?(word)
        word
    else 
        word.capitalize
    end
end 

words.first.capitalize!
words.join(" ")
end
```

Comment: Tell us what string you used for which you got `nil` ? There is actula answer is hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why do I get nil when I reverse the order of the words.first.capitalize and words.join(" ") lines?

This is the reason:

```
"abb".capitalize # => "Abb"
"Abb".capitalize! # => nil
"Abb".capitalize # => "Abb"
```

[**`String.capitalize!`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize-21) says:

> Modifies str by converting the first character to uppercase and the remainder to lowercase. ***Returns nil if no changes are made***. Note: case conversion is effective only in ASCII region.

When you are putting the line `words.first.capitalize!` at the end of your method, the `String.capitalize!` tried to capitalize the word which is already capitalized. You are using the `bang(!)` version, so, as per the documentation, you are getting `nil`.

One example:

```
def titleize(x)
  words = x.split(" ").collect do |word|
      if %w(the and of).include?(word)
          word
      else 
          word.capitalize
      end
  end 

  words.join(" ")
  words.first.capitalize!
end

titleize("he great book") # => nil
```

Probably your input string was not containing any of the words you listed here `%w(the and of)`, when you were testing. I would recommend you to use [**`String#capitalize`**](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html#method-i-capitalize) instead.

Comment: In English, we don't use  `:-`. It's not a stylistic decision, it's proper punctuation to use `:` only, with no preceding space.  Also, a space follows a comma in a sentence to delimit words, just as if there was no comma.

Comment: @theTinMan Thanks for correcting it. I am not that much of good in English! It is my third language :(

Answer (score 2):

Methods on the [string class](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/String.html) that modify the string in place, like `capitalize!` (and `gsub!`, `delete!`, etc), only return the string when changes have been made to it. When no modifications have been made they return `nil`:

```
irb(main):007:0> "the".capitalize!
=> "The"
irb(main):008:0> "The".capitalize!
=> nil
```

The chances are that your string is already capitalized (unless it starts with "the", "and" or "over") so when you have your `capitalize!` call last, both `capitalize!` and your method return `nil` because the string is not modified.